# displaying multi-piece images with css

Tags: css, html, sliding-doors

I have a table where I'm trying to display two tabs on the first line of each cell. I've divided the left tab into three images (left, middle, right), and it displays some text. It's supposed to be aligned with the left margin. The right tab has no text and should be aligned with the right margin. In between the two tabs is a line at the bottom of the tabs connecting the two - the right tab is one image and the connector is also one image, so there are five images I want to display. It should also stretch to fit the text (which it's doing) and the cell (which it's not).

It should look something like this:

[Text]__[]

The left tab is displaying fine, but the right tab is not. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class='category'>
<span><span><span><span>".$results['category']."</span></span></span></span></div>
<div class='righttab'><span><span></span></span></div>
```

CSS

```
.category
    {
    display: block;
    }
.category *
    {
    height: 27px;
    }
.category span
    {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: rgb(240,208,128);
    }
.category span span
    {
    background: url(tabmiddle.png) top left repeat-x;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
.category span span span
    {
    background: url(tabright.png) top right no-repeat;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 19px;
    }
.category span span span span
    {
    background: url(tableft.png) top left no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 19px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    }
.righttab
    {
    display:block;
    float: right;
    }
.righttab span
    {
    background: url(topborder.png) top repeat-x;
    display: block;
    }
.righttab span span
    {
    background: url(righttab.png) top right no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 75px;
    }
```

Comment: fwiw it's hard to envision it without seeing the images. When I copied and pasted your code into jsbin.com it didn't tell me much. From a 300,000ft point of view I would look into [css sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) which is about creating a box in CSS for your image. It's kind of like having a sticker sheet and being able to apply it wherever you want on your website.

Comment: Here's the window I'm trying to do: [link](http://eq2wire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/8yearvetreward-examine.jpg). There are two repeatable images, the middle of the left box and the top border (since the cells, unlike in the link) can be different width), and I'm not getting that right tab over there.

Comment: hmm, maybe this could help: [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex-direction) only lets a div expand horizontally which can preserve the images you have in between the right top (Bauble, Potion) and the x-out tab. This is a new feature in CSS3 (meaning it won't work on old browsers).